# Specific package version with conda-forge

Tags: python, keras, installation, conda, conda-forge

I am trying to install a specific `Keras` version from `Keras 1 API` using `conda-forge`, because

> **`$ conda search keras`**

returns only the following `Keras 2 API` options:

```
keras                        2.0.8            py35h86bcf3e_0  defaults
                             2.0.8            py27h242e9fd_0  defaults
                             2.0.8            py36h39110e4_0  defaults
```

> whereas **`$ conda search keras --channel conda-forge`**

return more options, apart from the usual channels, like so:

```
keras                        2.0.8            py35h86bcf3e_0  defaults
                             2.0.8            py27h242e9fd_0  defaults
                             2.0.8            py36h39110e4_0  defaults
                             1.0.7                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             1.0.7                    py34_0  conda-forge
                             1.0.7                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             1.0.7                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             1.2.2                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             1.2.2                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             1.2.2                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.0                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.0                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.0                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.1                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.1                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.1                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py27_1  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py35_1  conda-forge
                             2.0.2                    py36_1  conda-forge
                             2.0.4                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.4                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.4                    py36_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.6                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.6                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.6                    py36_0  conda-forge
                          *  2.0.9                    py27_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.9                    py35_0  conda-forge
                             2.0.9                    py36_0  conda-forge
```

so, is it possible to install a `1.x` version using `conda-forge`? I can't find any documentation.

if so, what is the proper syntax for the installation?

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge keras=1.0.7`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way you install any specific version from that information is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras=1.0.7=py27_0
```

Which is of the format

```
conda install <package_name>=<version>=<build_string>
```

If you want to choose which channel (otherwise `defaults` is chosen by default):

```
conda install -c <channel> <package_name>=<version>=<build_string>
```

***Note:*** The comment above (+1) already solved the question, this answer yet adds some details and strives to improve readability.